# 12.04 - Update Manager - failed - previous update incomplete

Tags: updates

A regular update failed with the message:

> Previous installation hasn't been completed
>
> The installation could have failed because of an error in the corresponding software package or it was cancelled in an unfriendly way. You have to repair this before you can install or remove any further software.

Based on hints I found, I did `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. The latter terminated with:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
linux-generic-pae linux-headers-generic-pae linux-image-generic-pae
The following packages will be upgraded:
apport apt-xapian-index aptdaemon ca-certificates firefox firefox-globalmenu
firefox-locale-en libsnmp-base libsnmp15 libsvn1 linux-firmware
linux-libc-dev mime-support openssh-client python-httplib2 python-keyring
ssh-askpass-gnome tzdata ubuntu-system-service unattended-upgrades
20 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
E: The package index files are corrupted. No Filename: field for package tzdata.
```

I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove some files

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Force the installation of `tzdata` via

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall tzdata
```

After that

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Many thanks, A.B.  Your directions worked perfectly and restored my system - and peace of mind!